# When does the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality become an equality?

Tags: vector-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

For two vectors $|f\rangle$ and $|g\rangle$, the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality becomes an equality when $$|h\rangle=|f\rangle-\frac{\langle f|g\rangle}{\langle g|g\rangle}|g\rangle$$ is a null vector. This happens when $|f\rangle$ is linearly dependent on $|g\rangle$ i.e. $|f\rangle=\alpha|g\rangle$ where $\alpha$ is a complex number.

But if we substitute this into the expression of $|h\rangle$ above we get, $$|h\rangle=\alpha|g\rangle-\alpha^*\frac{\langle g|g\rangle}{\langle g|g\rangle}|g\rangle=(\alpha-\alpha^*)|g\rangle$$ which is nonzero unless $\alpha$ is real.

What is wrong with my argument?

Comment: You probably want $\langle g | f\rangle$ in the numerator of the coefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your vector $|h\rangle$ is meant to be the coprojection of $f$ onto the span of $g$. For it to be that, when you take the inner product of $f$ with $g$, $f$ must appear in the linear position, not the conjugate-linear position. Which position that actually is varies somewhat among authors, but generally in bra-ket notation the inner product is linear in the kets, i.e. in the second position, which seems to be how you're doing it.

In other words you should have had $|h\rangle=|f\rangle-\frac{\langle g|f\rangle}{\langle g|g\rangle}|g\rangle$, and then the problem disappears.

Comment: Please see Proof 3 here @Ian https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Proofs z, u, and v are respectively h, f, and g in my notation.

Comment: @mithusengupta123 Yes, as they say there, they are using the convention that $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ is linear in the *first* argument instead of the second. Physicists usually use the opposite convention.

Answer (score 1):

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality *does* become an equality when your condition is satisfied (provided the vectors are of the proposed form $|f\rangle=\alpha|g\rangle$), but not *only when it is*. The equality is trivial if $|f\rangle$ or  $|g\rangle$ are null vectors, so let us assume they aren't. The condition we need is $$\langle f|f\rangle=\frac{\langle f|g\rangle \langle g|f\rangle}{\langle g|g\rangle}$$ which only requires $|f\rangle=\alpha|g\rangle$ just as you stated (to prove this condition from the above equation you may write $|f\rangle-\alpha|g\rangle=|u\rangle$ and then prove that $|u\rangle$ is zero). In fact, if you let $\langle g|$ act on the vectors from your first equation, you will find that $\langle g|h\rangle=\langle g|f\rangle - \langle f|g\rangle$, so $|h\rangle$ is only a null vector if $\langle g|f\rangle$ is a real number, which is why your assumption leads to real $\alpha$.

Comment: No, Cauchy-Schwarz is indeed an equality precisely when $f$ and $g$ are parallel, in which case the coprojection of one onto the other will be zero (if it is defined). The OP just made an error in their definition of the coprojection.

Comment: @Ian yes. But because of that error the condition he wrote will only lead to the correct result if $\alpha$ is real. It should be $\langle g|f\rangle$  rather than $\langle f|g\rangle$. They will be the same thing when that inner product is real, which only happens when $\alpha$ is.